# How to transition user from (Lottie) Splash Animation to MainActivity automatically after animation finishes?

Tags: java, android, android-animation, lottie

I want this Lottie animation to exit after it finishes animating, then it should send me to the `mainactivity`

It's a splash screen, and I want it to `load animation`, `finish animation`, then  send me to `mainactivity`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
        android:id="@+id/dd"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="204dp"
        android:translationX="80dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
        app:lottie_loop="true"
        app:lottie_rawRes="@raw/gold">

    </com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView>

    <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
        android:id="@+id/dd2"
        android:layout_width="440dp"
        android:layout_height="256dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="124dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.965"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
        app:lottie_loop="true"
        app:lottie_rawRes="@raw/luffy">

    </com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

and here is my mainactivity

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import com.studioidan.httpagent.HttpAgent;
import com.studioidan.httpagent.StringCallback;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView textViewl;
    private RecyclerView recy;
    private TextView textView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private List<PersonUtils> personUtilsList;
    private int ints = 1;
    private DrawerLayout Mdrawer;
    private DatabaseTool databaseTool;

    private ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>> listmap = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textViewl = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        setTitle("Latest Chapters");
        databaseTool = new DatabaseTool();
        init();
    }
    public void init() {
        databaseTool.makeData(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath(),"fav");
        recy = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recy);
        Mdrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout) ;
        recy.setHasFixedSize(true);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titlead);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());

        recy.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        personUtilsList = new ArrayList<>();
        final Document[] document = new Document[1];
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
        //Get Document object after parsing the html from given url.
        final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        dialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
            String url = "..." + ints;
            HttpAgent.get(url).
                    goString(new StringCallback() {
                        @Override
                        protected void onDone(boolean success, String results) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                            if (success) {
                                document[0] = Jsoup.parse(results);
                                //Get images from document object.
                                Elements images =
                                        document[0].select(".story-list").get(0).children();
                                //Iterate images and print image attributes.
                                int iss = images.size();
                                iss = --iss;
                                for (int i = 0; i <= iss; i++) {
                                    personUtilsList.add(new PersonUtils(images.get(i).getElementsByTag("img").attr("alt"),
                                            images.get(i).child(2).text(), images.get(i).getElementsByTag("img").attr("src"),images.get(i).child(0).attr("href")));
                                };
                                mAdapter = new CustomRecyclerAdapter(getApplicationContext(), personUtilsList);
                                recy.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                            } else {
                                showMessage(getErrorMessage());
                            }
                        }
                    });
        recy.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                if (!recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1)) {
                    ints = ints+1;
                    final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                    dialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");
                    dialog.setCancelable(false);
                    dialog.show();
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
                    String url = "..." + ints;
                    HttpAgent.get(url).
                            goString(new StringCallback() {
                                @Override
                                protected void onDone(boolean success, String results) {
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                    if (success) {
                                        List<PersonUtils> personUtils = new ArrayList<>();
                                        document[0] = Jsoup.parse(results);
                                        //Get images from document object.
                                        Elements images =
                                                document[0].select("").get(0).children();
                                        //Iterate images and print image attributes.
                                        int iss = images.size();
                                        iss = --iss;
                                        for (int i = 0; i <= iss; i++) {
                                            personUtils.add(new PersonUtils(images.get(i).getElementsByTag("img").attr("alt"),
                                                    images.get(i).child(2).text(), images.get(i).getElementsByTag("img").attr("src"),images.get(i).child(0).attr("href")));
                                        };
                                        int insertIndex = mAdapter.getItemCount();
                                        personUtilsList.addAll(insertIndex,personUtils);
                                        mAdapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(insertIndex, personUtils.size());
                                        showMessage(""+ints);
                                    } else {
                                        showMessage(getErrorMessage());
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                }
            }
        });
    }
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void showMessage(String s) {
        TextView te = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        te.setText("<        "+s+"        >");
        LinearLayout layout2 = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
        layout2.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        layout2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        layout2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.runded);
        layout2.setElevation(8);
        layout2.addView(te);
        Toast to = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
        to.setView(layout2);
        to.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        to.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
       super.onDestroy();
       clearApplicationData();
            // Cancel running task(s) to avoid memory leaks
    }

    public void opendrwer(View view) {
        try {
            Mdrawer.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Mdrawer.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
        }
    }


    public void opengenre(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(),GenreActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    public void clearApplicationData()
    {
        File cache = getCacheDir();
        File appDir = new File(cache.getParent());
        if (appDir.exists()) {
            String[] children = appDir.list();
            for (String s : children) {
                if (!s.equals("lib")) {
                    deleteDir(new File(appDir, s));
                    Log.i("TAG", "**************** File /data/data/APP_PACKAGE/" + s + " DELETED *******************");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public static boolean deleteDir(File dir)
    {
        if (dir.isDirectory()) {
        String[] children = dir.list();
        for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
            if (!success) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
        return dir.delete();
    }

    public void clearcac(View view) {

    }

    public void openSpoilers(View view) {
        Intent ddd = new Intent();
        ddd.setClass(getApplicationContext(),Spoilers.class);
        startActivity(ddd);
    }
}
```

(did not include scraped urls)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can add listener to played animation

**xml**

```
<com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
    android:id="@+id/lottieView"
    android:layout_width="440dp"
    android:layout_height="256dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="124dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.965"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
    app:lottie_loop="false" // this is required to listen to end of animation
    app:lottie_rawRes="@raw/luffy">
```

**code**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    LottieAnimationView lottieView=findViewById(R.id.lottieView);
    lottieView.addAnimatorListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
            // do here the action you want 
        }
        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {

        }
    });


}
```